Как скомпилировать .java файл в .class на Windows 11?
У меня есть java файл который я хочу скомпилировать в class. Но вот незадача! У меня установлена Windows 11 (у меня есть компьютер на windows 10 но сейчас у меня нет доступа к нему). Вопрос: как скомпилировать .java в .class на Windows 11?

Точно также, качаете jdk и компилируете с помощью javac

Этот вопрос похож на: Как закомпилировать .java файл в .class?; Cant find symbol. [X2]; Не могу открыть скомпилированную программу .class через командную строку. Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.


Открываешь консоль.
Переходишь в директорию, где находится файл с исходным кодом.
Вводишь команду javac Имя_файла.java и выполняешь ее.

